# Is there a way to overlay an application over a full-screened program?

Tags: user-interface, architecture

I am looking to develop an application which is essentially a timer window which is always shown on the screen in front of any other application and never falls to the background when focusing other windows. An example is when I play a full-screen game I would like this timer to be overlaying the game and when I click the timer buttons on the window it does not close the game.

Any ideas how I can achieve this in C#/java/C++?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

C#: try setting the AlwaysOnTop property of the window (form)
java: call the setAlwaysOnTop(true) on the frame or dialog

Comment: But the other requirement is where I am having trouble. If I click a button on the frame it will close the fullscreen program and focus the window. Any idea how to not close the fullscreen program in the process?

Comment: Did you try making the frame modal? In C#, you can do this by calling not the Show() method, but ShodDialog() on the form.

Comment: I dont think you get what Im trying to do. Any program, game or application I run on my computer I need my C# form to always be on top. However, using setAlwaysonTop does not work when games go full screen ect...

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to achieve can be achieved with the property  [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of the form in C#, and [setAlwaysOnTop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29) on a Java Window ...

In C++ on Windows you have to call the **SetWindowPos** function and passing as argument : **HWND_TOPMOST** attribue.

**UPDATE**

Since you have an application in fullscreen mode try setting your application in foreground with the Win32 API function : [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

Otherwise you can try to avoid using the Win32 [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with something like this :

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.Activate();
```

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer and let me know, i haven't tested, but could work ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this using the example of Dota 2 in full screen mode (DirectX11) Win10, I tried all sorts of flags and methods from the comments above and none of the options worked. We all proceed from the fact that most games run faster in fullscreen mode and we want to make an overlay specifically for this mode. Perhaps I lack technical knowledge, but after delving into this topic, I came to the conclusion that it is impossible to make an overlay for a fullscreen mod. So just install the window without a frame.