# injecting text to process without injecting dll

Tags: c#, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to overlay an application over a full-screened program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339295/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-an-application-over-a-full-screened-program)

Is it possible in C# to inject a text to process (like fraps for example), but without using any .dll injections?

Thanks in advance for responses.

@update
"A text" means some fast refreshing labels or something, which will show informations e.g.:

```
Name:Test
Pos: x=123,y=456,z=0
Level: Unknown
Something.....
```

Comment: Please add some code illustrating what you are trying to do, or illustrating ".dll injections" that you are trying to avoid.  It is hard to tell what your question is really about.  Thanks!

Comment: Should the tag be "graphics" instead of "injection"

Answer (score 0):

You can use automation to send keyboard actions and suchlike to another program. Otherwise if there is no exposed API then things look bleak. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744111/sending-keystrokes-to-a-program) for an overview on the methods you use to send keystrokes.

**EDIT**: What you're asking for is not injection, it's an overlay. What you're looking to do is take control of the display buffer so that your overlay always has a higher z-index than whatever is being rendered. Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339295/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-an-application-over-a-full-screened-program)

Comment: You haven't understood me. I'm asking if it is possible to inject text like here: http://www.gamereplays.org/community/uploads/post-441-1286696462.jpg, not send keys like keyboard or something

Comment: @answer to edit: If it is possible, I'm looking for method to overlay only one, concrete window without using additional forms or the more dll inject